# Connecting one foreign key to multiple tables (primary keys)

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am developing an application for making quotations. First you make cost break down (or calculation) and upon that result you add item to quotation. The problem is that i have many product, so each category of a product will have its own cost break down form with different parameters to be filled in. If I will have only one table for cost breakdown, then it will be huge (a lot of fields in table). I have a feeling that this is not the right approach. So I came up with diagram below:

[image: My diagram]

Is this solution even possible, or I must have "N" (if I have N-tables) different FK for each cost break down table? Do you have any better solutions?

I have another question if my linking table "Quotation_QtnDetail" is necessary?

Comment: Use another table with a 1-1 relationship for all calculation tables. The use this table as the primary key table for your foreign key. It's easy to connect many tables on a 1-1 relationship, but not on a 1-m relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to store a reference to a particular value in one of these tables by having a `CalculationType` column indicating which table the record is in, along with a generic reference ID column (containing the ID of the relevant record). For example, if you were storing a `CalcId` of 123 and a `CalculationType` of 2, this would point to the record with ID 123 in the `Calc2` table.

The downside to doing this is you're going to lose the ability to validate your data using FK constraints, and it will also make joins to your calculation tables a bit more complicated.

Regarding the `Quotation_QtnDetail` table, unless a `QtnDetail` record could ever be linked to multiple `Quotation` records, there is no need for this extra linking table. Instead, just link it directly by adding a `QtnId` column to the `QtnDetail` table. Similarly, you may also be able to remove the `Calc_QtnItm` table if an item is only ever linked to a single calculation record.

Comment: Thank you. I will use your solution with CalculationType. But how can i manage that with sql queries? Do i use CASE statement?

Comment: Depends on what you need to do. You could left join all of the tables (e.g. LEFT JOIN Calc1 ON Calc1.CalLinkId = Calc_QtnItm.CalcId AND Calc_QtnItem.CalculationType = 1) and end up selecting a lot of NULL values, or you could just have your application do a separate query to get the calc info from the relevant table (based on Calc_QtnItem.CalculationType).